Estimating Average Marginal Effects with Ordered Logistic Regression
I am estimating a series of ordered logistic regression models for a 4-level ordered dependent variable and I am trying to estimate the average marginal effect (using {marginaleffects}) of moving from 0 to 1 (treatment values). Below is an example of my code:
model <- polr(outcome ~ treatment + adjustment, data = data)

ame.robust <- avg_comparisons(model, variables = treatment, 
                vcov = ~ cluster.id). 

When I do this, I get marginal differences for each level in the outcome variable. That is, there is a marginal effect of moving from 0 to 1 for each level of the outcome variable (AME of moving from 0 to 1 when outcome = 1, when outcome = 2, etc.).
Is this the correct interpretation of an AME for an ordered outcome? In other words, if this is the correct interpretation, would it be fair to say that the average marginal effect of moving from control to treatment for units whose outcome value is 1 = X? (And this would obviously apply for the other 3 levels as well).

I wouldn't say "AME of moving from 0 to 1 when outcome=1". I would say something like: "moving from 0 to 1 on the treatment is associated with an increase of estimate in the probability that Y=1".

Great, thank you @Vincent. I was struggling a bit with the interpretation, but this cleared things up a bit.

See: https://marginaleffects.com/vignettes/categorical.html
